# Match records with specific ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let say I have this query to match an employee with the specific orders `1982` and `138923`, is there another way without using `having` and `group by` clause ?

I want to sort out the employees that have two or more specific order ids.

```
SELECT [EmployeeId], COUNT([OrderId]) 
FROM [dbo].[EmployeeOrderRelation]
WHERE [OrderId] IN (1982, 138923)
GROUP BY [EmployeeId]
HAVING count([OrderId]) > 1;
```

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to not use this correct query?

Comment: Not really but we are trying to put it inside an specific logic with a dynamic query, so in this case, the whole query is different, that's why

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT er.*
FROM [dbo].[EmployeeOrderRelation] er
WHERE [OrderId] IN (1982, 138923) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM [dbo].[EmployeeOrderRelation] er1 
              WHERE er1.[EmployeeId] = er.[EmployeeId] AND er1.[OrderId] <> er.[OrderId]
             );
```

I don't know why you need different version of the query instead of aggregation query, if the performance concern then this version some time helpful in performance if you have a right index on (`EmployeeId`, `OrderId`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery

```
SELECT a.* 
 FROM [dbo].[EmployeeOrderRelation] a
 WHERE [OrderId] IN (1982, 138923) and exists (select 1 from [dbo].[EmployeeOrderRelation] b where a.[EmployeeId]=b.[EmployeeId] and b.[OrderId] IN (1982, 138923) having count(orderid)>=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `INTERSECT` to return EmployeeId having both values:

```
SELECT [EmployeeId] FROM [dbo].[EmployeeOrderRelation] WHERE [OrderId] = 1982
INTERSECT
SELECT [EmployeeId] FROM [dbo].[EmployeeOrderRelation] WHERE [OrderId] = 138923
```

Or do a self join:

```
select t1.[EmployeeId]
from [dbo].[EmployeeOrderRelation] t1
join [dbo].[EmployeeOrderRelation] t2
    on t1.[EmployeeId] = t2.[EmployeeId]
WHERE t1.[OrderId] = 1982
  AND t2.[OrderId] = 138923
```